# How to access the variable in struct which is in vector in a struct

Tags: c++, struct, stdvector

How could I access my variable in struct which is in vector. Here I have a following code

```
 struct sam
 {
    double x;
    int    y;
    std::vector< struct jon > jhon;
 };

 struct jon
 {
    int  id;
    char name[64];    
 };

 class foo
 {
  public:
    void getdata();

  private;
    sam   s;
 };

 void foo:: getdata()
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
   {
     s.jhon[i].id = 5;
   }
 }
```

I couldn't access the variable id. I thinking, I am accessing in a wrong way. Can anyone suggest me the best way to access the variable through vector struct.

Comment: The access looks correct on first glance, the only issue I see is that you assume jhon to have at least two elements, but I don't see it initialized anywhere... what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Which do you mean - do you get a crash, or do you get a compilation error?

Comment: I am getting a segmentation fault @Demosthenes

Comment: Improve the question by clarifying whether `foo::getdata` expects the vector to already have two elements previously added, or whether you mean for it to now add two elements.

Comment: foo::getdata reads a variable from external file. I just want to read a data from the the imported file and assigned to the variables which is inside the struct  @acraig5075

Comment: @CodeConfusion Then the first thing that `getdata` should do is to `s.jhon.resize(2);` so that it contains that number of elements.

Comment: You have to define `struct jon` before `struct sam`

Comment: Yeah wait how does this even compile? It does (if you fix `private;` and add headers) but how?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's UB NDR to have class member of vector of incomplete type, so compiler may allow it.  `private;` is definitely a hard error however

Comment: @M.M. Mmmmmmmmm.

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t add any “jon”s to the vector so it’s empty. You can’t access from an empty vector.

Comment: I have a some element in jon. how it can be an empty struct. could you please elaborate  the mistake

Comment: @CodeConfusion: _"I have a some element in jon"_ Not in the code you showed us.

Comment: "jon is a struct and it has some variables inside. I try to access the variable @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: Your vector (jhon) didn't have any jons in it. You would need to add them  with foo::s.jhon.push_back(), which is private.

Comment: @CodeConfusion: _"it has some variables inside"_ Not in the code you showed us.

Comment: Premium c++ for beginners

Comment: @CodeConfusion: That book does not appear to exist.

Comment: C++ primer.. that was spell mistake